# How to create a global tab bar

Tags: blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

How to have a global tab bar for an application? bar will have 4 buttonsand will be seen on every screen.

Comment: rupesh,

Check this question:

[enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9160378/how-to-create-tab-bar-application-ui-in-blackberry

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to create Tab bar application ui in blackberry?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9160378/how-to-create-tab-bar-application-ui-in-blackberry)